# Django template language is not recognized

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django projcet. Yesterday when I left the project I didn't have any problems. Today when I opend the project my {% load static %} was gray, and the next line which is "<!doctype html>" gives me "Unexpected tokens". My project works fine except the templates. I work in a virtual envirment, have my project on github: https://github.com/FREDYKRUGE/Mist2.git. P.S I work with PyCharm proffesional

I tried installing all the dependecies again, they were all satisfied, tried activating the venv, it was okay. My docker is up and running.

A photo of the template I am talking about https://imgur.com/a/T0WWpEI

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Mist2.common',
    'Mist2.games',
    'Mist2.accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Mist2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Mist2.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "MistDB",
        "USER": "postgres-user",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MistUser'
```

That's docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: MistDB  # Replace 'MistDB' with the same value you used in settings.py
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres-user  # Replace 'postgres-user' with the same value you used in settings.py
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password  # Replace 'password' with the same value you used in settings.py
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build:
      context: D:\SoftuniProjects\Mist2  # The path to your Django project directory
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # Use the newly created Dockerfile for building the Django web application image
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  # Adjust this command based on your Django setup
    volumes:
      - .:/app  # Mount the current directory (Django project) to the '/app' directory in the container
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  # Map host port 8000 to container port 8000

volumes:
  postgres_data:`
```

That's my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.4

# Install PostgreSQL development packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install the required dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Start the Django development server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

UPDATE: I rescaned indexe, didn't work, reopened my project, didn't work, dropped shared indexes (whatever that means), it worked. I got to that point by 'Main menu -> File -> Repair IDE'

Comment: Your link gives a 404, but regardless, you should not share links to external resources, since these might be removed in the future. Provie the relevant template and settings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the static-Files is "mysite/static/"

When you want to access to your "style.css" for example you should use "/static/style.css" instead of "/mysite/style.css"

**EDIT:**

Change this part of your settings.py

With absolute path:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:/django-project/mysite/static')
```

or relative:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
)
```

and don't forget to set the STATIC_URL!

Comment: It's not a problem with static files. It's a problem with django or django templates themselves.